# Add JMeter plugin programmatically - non gui mode

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to use jmeter-plugins. 
Does it have to be placed only under `/lib/ext` folder?
Is there any way for me to refer to the plugin jar using some properties?
(like `user.classpath` property to refer to my custom lib)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to put JMeter plugin jars in the `lib/ext` directory, then define the property `search_paths` in `jmeter.properties`.

Comment: Thanks. I thought i thoroughly checked jmeter.properties!! :(

Answer (score 0):

After placing the plugin manager jar in the /lib/ext/ you need to do the following to install a particular plugin.

Download the latest cmdrunner from this URL by changing the version.

```
wget http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=kg/apc/cmdrunner/2.2/cmdrunner-2.2.jar
```

Copy the cmdrunner to jmeter/lib/ directory

```
mv cmdrunner-2.2.jar apache-jmeter-5.1.1/lib/
```

Execute the following command to generate script file PluginsManagerCMD

```
java -cp apache-jmeter-5.1.1/lib/ext/jmeter-plugins-manager-1.3.jar org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMDInstaller
```

After the script is generated, you can use it to install a particular plugin

```
apache-jmeter-5.1.1/bin/PluginsManagerCMD.sh status
apache-jmeter-5.1.1/bin/PluginsManagerCMD.sh available
apache-jmeter-5.1.1/bin/PluginsManagerCMD.sh install jpgc-tst=2.5
```

Comment: @Mino if you verified and it worked, you may upvote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download cmdrunner in lib folder

   ```
   cd apache-jmeter-5.4/lib
   curl -O https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/kg/apc/cmdrunner/2.2.1/cmdrunner-2.2.1.jar
   ```

   download-cmd
2. Download jmeter plugin Manager in lib/ext folder

   ```
   cd ext/
   curl -O https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/kg/apc/jmeter-plugins-manager/1.6/jmeter-plugins-manager-1.6.jar
   ```
3. Install plugins

   ```
   cd ..
   java  -jar cmdrunner-2.2.1.jar --tool org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMD install jpgc-webdriver
   ```