# Not able to install Jmeter plugin manager in Linux Mint

Tags: linux, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Once run the JMeter from terminal of Linuxmint. the following error is thrown and in JMeter UI mode, UI->Option-> there is no any plugin manager available.

```
org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerMenuCreator: Was unable to install pmgr cmdline tool java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /usr/share/jmeter/bin/PluginsManagerCMD.bat
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.implDelete(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:244)
at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.deleteIfExists(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:108)
at java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(Files.java:1165)
at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Files.java:3004)
at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMDInstaller.writeOut(PluginManagerCMDInstaller.java:24)
at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMDInstaller.main(PluginManagerCMDInstaller.java:12)
at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerMenuCreator.getMenuItemsAtLocation(PluginManagerMenuCreator.java:16)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar.addPluginsMenuItems(JMeterMenuBar.java:579)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar.makeOptionsMenu(JMeterMenuBar.java:356)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar.createMenuBar(JMeterMenuBar.java:270)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar.<init>(JMeterMenuBar.java:163)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.MainFrame.init(MainFrame.java:458)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.java:216)
at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.startGui(JMeter.java:234)
at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.start(JMeter.java:382)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:259)

2019/01/13 04:46:19 ERROR - org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerMenuCreator: Failed to load Plugins Manager java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/protocol/HttpContext
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManager.<init>(PluginManager.java:56)
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManager.<clinit>(PluginManager.java:44)
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerMenuItem.<init>(PluginManagerMenuItem.java:30)
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerMenuCreator.getMenuItemsAtLocation(PluginManagerMenuCreator.java:22)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar.addPluginsMenuItems(JMeterMenuBar.java:579)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar.makeOptionsMenu(JMeterMenuBar.java:356)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar.createMenuBar(JMeterMenuBar.java:270)
```

Comment: Here's how to install a plugin on linux https://stackoverflow.com/a/57849654/1875434

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several issues:

1. By default in Linux Mint you have **JMeter 2.13** from repositories which is a little bit [outdated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_JMeter) (released on 2015-03-14). Therefore there is no chance to use the latest Plugins Manager with JMeter 2.13, you need to try one of the [previous versions](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/kg.apc/jmeter-plugins-manager)
2. You don't have write permissions to the folder where JMeter is installed, you will need to grant yourself permissions using [chown](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uchown.htm) command like:

   ```
   sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /usr/share/jmeter
   ```

---

In general, according to JMeter Best Practices [you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version). The steps of obtaining [JMeter 5.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-new-jmeter-5) with the plugins manager are the following:

1. `cd ~`
2. `wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.0.zip`
3. `unzip apache-jmeter-5.0.zip`
4. `wget http://central.maven.org/maven2/kg/apc/jmeter-plugins-manager/1.3/jmeter-plugins-manager-1.3.jar -P apache-jmeter-5.0/lib/ext/`
5. `PATH=~/apache-jmeter-5.0/bin:$PATH && export PATH && jmeter`
6. That's it, you should now have the latest JMeter with the latest Plugins Manager up and running. Write down the command from the Step #5 and use it for launching JMeter